# UIView/StackView frame returning wrong .centers on larger screens?

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit

I am trying to find the true position of a UIView named playingCardContainer. You are seeing a snap shot of what is to be a much larger switch case. I have added some text to try to debug and see whats going on. On a smaller screen this works correctly, On a bigger screen its breaking. Here are some screenshots from an Iphone 15 Pro simulator and Iphone SE Simulator. These screenshots are from the same code. playingCardContainer is in view with all the cards in it.

I have included case 4 as an example because some views are embedded in another view, we have to convert it. Which works fine on both Small and Big devices. Am I missing something?

The variable ClearPoint attempts finds the center of the UIView and from there we calculate where to draw it from, alternatively we can also get minx,miny. Nothing seems to be working.
[image: Iphone 15 Pro]
[image: Iphone Se]

```
case 3:
            //var clearPoint = playingCardContainer.center // similiar result
            //var clearPoint = playingCardContainer.convert(playingCardContainer.center, to: view.window) // completely wrong
            let containerFrame = playingCardContainer.frame
            let containerCenter = CGPoint(x: containerFrame.origin.x + containerFrame.width / 2, y: containerFrame.origin.y + containerFrame.height / 2)
            var clearPoint = view.convert(containerCenter, from: playingCardContainer.superview)
            
            let width: CGFloat = playingCardContainer.frame.width // Use the container's width
            let height: CGFloat = playingCardContainer.frame.height // Use the container's height
            let minX = containerFrame.minX
            let minY = containerFrame.minY
            //let minX = playingCardContainer.frame.minX
            //let minY = playingCardContainer.frame.minY
            let Text = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: clearPoint.x, y: clearPoint.y, width: 50, height: 15))
            Text.text = "center"
            Text.textAlignment = .center
            
            let Text2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: containerFrame.minX, y: containerFrame.minY, width: 50, height: 15))
            Text2.text = "Top left"
            Text2.textAlignment = .center
            Text2.textColor = .green
            
            view.addSubview(Text)
            view.addSubview(Text2)
            ShowUserGuide(atStep: 3, clearPoint: &clearPoint, containerWidth: width, containerHeight: height, minX: minX, minY: minY )
            
        case 4:
            var clearPoint = noDiscardsRemainingLabel.convert(noDiscardsRemainingLabel.center, to: view.window)
            let width: CGFloat = noDiscardsRemainingLabel.frame.width + 30  // Use the container's width
            let height: CGFloat = noDiscardsRemainingLabel.frame.height + 30 // Use the container's height
            ShowUserGuide(atStep: 4, clearPoint: &clearPoint, containerWidth: width, containerHeight: height)
```

You can ignore this part of the code, its just hows its drawn on to the screen, all the necessary points are put on to it.

```
func ShowUserGuide(atStep:Int, clearPoint:inout CGPoint, containerWidth:CGFloat, containerHeight: CGFloat, adjustClearPoint:Bool = true , flipBox:Bool = false, minX:CGFloat = 0, minY:CGFloat = 0)
    {
        if flipBox
        {
            step0roundLabelView = RoundedTextLabel(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.minX + 10, y: view.frame.maxY - 110, width: 300, height: 100), text: HowToPlayGuide.shared.getGuideText(atStep: atStep), textSize: 15)
        } else
        {
            step0roundLabelView = RoundedTextLabel(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.maxX - 310, y: view.frame.maxY - 110, width: 300, height: 100), text: HowToPlayGuide.shared.getGuideText(atStep: atStep), textSize: 15)
        }
        view.addSubview(step0roundLabelView!)
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DismissGuideView(_:)))
        tapGestureRecognizer.name = String(atStep)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        let maskView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        if adjustClearPoint
        {
            clearPoint.y = clearPoint.y - 20
        }
        var maskRect:CGRect
        if minY != 0
        {
            maskRect = CGRect(x:minX, y: minY, width: containerWidth, height: containerHeight)
        } else
        {
            maskRect = CGRect(x: clearPoint.x - containerWidth / 2, y: clearPoint.y - containerHeight / 2, width: containerWidth, height: containerHeight)
        }
        print("maskRect = \(maskRect)")
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(rect: maskView.bounds)
        //maskPath.addArc(withCenter: clearPoint, radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        maskPath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: maskRect))
        maskPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        animation.fromValue = lastMaskPath?.cgPath //UIBezierPath(rect: darkOverlayView!.layer.frame).cgPath
        animation.toValue = maskPath.cgPath //UIBezierPath(rect: maskRect).cgPath
        animation.duration = 1.0 // Set the animation duration
        maskLayer.add(animation, forKey: "pathAnimation2")
        
        darkOverlayView!.layer.mask = nil
        darkOverlayView!.layer.mask = maskLayer
        lastMaskPath = maskPath
    }
```

Comment: I still don't get the question, you mean that on the bigger screen width, the cards do not overlay each other as on the smaller screen width, do you?

Comment: @son on the bigger screen, playingCardContainer.center does not return actual center. I am trying to brighten only that View. Its done correctly on the smaller screen

Comment: It's hard to say in this circumstance. i.e, if you load the view from xib (which is currently designed for iP 11, let's assume that), at the time `viewDidLoad` loaded on iP bigger/smaller, its center doesn't right, that's why we need to use autoresizingmask/autolayout. You can print out `view.frame` to see the different.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/muDm7tb
It does use autolayout. Is there a different way for me to grab its exact x/y location using autolayout? @son

Comment: You're mixing autolayout and frame, why wouldn't you add constraints for two Labels and the container too?

Comment: When does the code run? You cannot obtain view geometry in `viewDidLoad`, for example

Comment: the two labels are just for me to do some testing to see what kind of results I get using clearPoint from playingCardContainer.frame, those two text aren't needed at all.

Comment: @matt they run at ViewWillAppear. Rest assured, by the time this case (3) called. View has already loaded

Comment: I'm not convinced. Try an experiment: If you move it to `viewDidAppear` does it work better?

Comment: @matt just tried to do it after viewDidAppear, no difference. mainly because this is kinda of sequence, its goes from 0->13. 
case 0 adds a text box on the screen,
case 1: brings up a new view controller. when dismissed a delegate is called to trigger case 2.
case 2: shows a label inside a view which loads correctly
case 3: Issue here.
When we reach case 3, the view has been there for at least... 10 seconds
Also all centers for views which are not embedded in another view have this issue. I can embede them as a solution but feels bad...

Comment: Print some frames, center etc in `viewDidLayoutSubViews()` vs `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()`, you might see the differences  if I understood correctly your issue.

Comment: print(playingCardContainer.center)

View Did Load
(398.0, 254.0)
view will appear
(398.0, 254.0)
viewDidLayoutSubviews
(471.5, 282.3333333333333)

Maybe this is the correct center? Ill have to see what viewDidLayoutSubviews does and see how I can extract this information as I see its running alot of times. @Larme

Comment: In a Nutshell, if you're using a XIB, viewDidLoad will have the views values of the xib set (for instance, if in Storyboard, you "set all the views" in iPhone SE frames, that'd be the values there). Same in didAppear, then the Layout (autoLayout) will be called to check all that with constraints settings, modify them if needed and call didLayoutSubViews. I'd recommend you to check AutoLayout documentation. If you rotate (and manage various orientations), the AutoLayout will also be checked (and so the didLayoutSubView called), etc.

Comment: When I just checked, when my function is called, I am already using the center from viewDidLayoutsubviews
viewDidLayoutSubviews
(471.5, 282.3333333333333)
Case 3 ClearPoint data Point Used :(471.5, 282.3333333333333)

@Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're points are off because your leading and trailing bounds for your UI elements are different in devices with a safe area(iPhone 15) and those without(iPhone SE).  There isn't enough code provided to pin down where the issue is but if you build you're UI using leading and trailing of the edges of the controller's `view.layoutMarginsGuide` you should get the same result on devices with and without safe areas.  The yellow areas in this screenshot illustrate the difference for your leading/trailing edges [image]

Comment: How do I get the width of the edges? In yellow? its different for each devices right? Let me understand ur saying the 2 yellow spots marked added together is what I need to offset this view. Which I find odd because case 4: works fine using convert when the view is in a subview of other views. But I will attempt regardless.

This view is built on UIKit and using Autolayout. Its then reference back to the vc file.

Comment: Hi again, This led me down the right path, the values i was getting was relative to safe area and not relative to the entire view. Therefore, the drawn areas seemed out of lined. By adding view.superview?.safeAreaInsets.left, to the Drawn position of, I was able to solve the issue on both large and smaller screens.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out!